# Transforming annotations for an object in an image

Tags: image, opencv, transformation, bounding-box

I've certain data set of images which has annotations for objects in that image. Annotations as in `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]` for the object in the image. How do I transform these coordinates to their new values when I resize the image while maintaining the aspect ratio ?

Comment: are you trying to extract a sub image with the coordinates? because that is different from resizing.

Comment: no, actually. Let's say, there is an object in an image. I would like to resize the image. Once the image is resized, the co-ordinates of the bounding box of that object in the image change. How do I get the new coordinates of the object in the image ?

Comment: Are you the one resizing the image? because you could also shrink or extend the coordinates of the object along with resizing. For example, if you are resizing the image by 0.5 the coordiniates must have resized to 0.5 too.

Comment: Yes, I'm resizing the images.

Comment: then whatever the factor you are resizing, multiply them to your xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax.

Comment: Okay, I get that. Thanks

Comment: Glad I helped. keep coding stay calm.

Comment: I want square images, what if the original images are not square shape ?

Comment: you can still use rect to get a square image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148953/discussion-between-harman-and-ray-hong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply resizing, use resize. For example:

```
using namespace cv;
Mat img;
img = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat dst;
resize(img, dst, Size(xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin));
```

If you are extracting sub image, use Rect. For example:

```
using namespace cv;
Mat original_img;
Rect roi;
roi.x = xmin;
roi.y = ymin;
roi.width = xmax-xmin;
roi.height = ymax-ymin;

Mat subimage = original_img(roi);
```

If you are trying to find out the coordinates(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) after resize,

multiply them by the factor of the resize.

For example, if the resize is by the factor of 0.5,

the coordinates(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) are now (xmin*0.5,xmax*0.5,ymin*0.5,ymax*0.5).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package too: https://github.com/italojs/resize_dataset_pascalvoc
it's easy to use `python3 main.py -p <IMAGES_&_XML_PATH> --output <IMAGES_&_XML> --new_x <NEW_X_SIZE> --new_y <NEW_X_SIZE> --save_box_images <FLAG>"`